# How can I use MIN clause to fetch records from the same row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am testing a query that looks like this.

```
Select DISTINCT col1,                               
    col2,                           
    case when MIN(col3) like '' then '0' else MIN(col3) end as col3,                            
    case when MIN(col4) like '' then '0' else MIN(col4) end as col4,                            
    case when MIN(col5) like '' then '0' else MIN(col5) end as col5,                                                        
From CPDG As CPDG                               
INNER JOIN LKP As LKP                               
ON CPDG.asset_id = LKP.asset_id     
GROUP BY col1, col2,
```

This gives me distinct records per row, so initially I thought this is correct, but when I remove the aggregation and look closely at the un-aggregated data, the MIN clause is pulling records from different rows.

Here is an example of the aggregation:

[image]

Here is an example of the un-aggregated data (yellow indicates matches in the image above):

[image]
How can I change the query to pull all records from the same row?  Maybe it requires `rank` or `partition by`.  Just thinking out loud here.  Thoughts?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What row do you want?

Comment: So how do we choose which record we should display: for example, should we pick the record that has the minimum `col2`?

Comment: The result can be arbitrary, I just want the final result to consist of records that are actually sourced from the same row.

Comment: Images of data are *really* unhelpful. We can't use them. Data is `text` and should be supplied `text`. Or, even better, as DDL and DML statements.

Comment: So which row do you expect?  The one with minimum col2 for each col1?

Comment: The results of a SQL query are not abitrary. Please show us the results that you do expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total blind guess, but do you mean:

```
Select col1,                               
       col2, 
       (SELECT MIN(V.Col) FROM (VALUES(Col3),(Col4),(Col5))V(Col)) AS MinCol,...
```

Comment: Oh, yes, I see what's happening now!  Ok, this totally makes sense.  It seems like I would need a subquery to get the initial population and then query the MIN or DISTINCT col1.  How can I do that?

Comment: Without sample data and expected results, I can only guess, @ASH .